# Add integers of two lists of lists together

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, addition, nested-lists

I am trying to write a function that accepts two lists-of-lists of numbers and returns one list-of-lists with each of the corresponding numbers in the two given lists-of-lists added together. Without using any third-party libraries (without using pandas for example).

It should work something like this:

```python
>>> matrix1 = [[1, -2], [-3, 4]]
>>> matrix2 = [[2, -1], [0, -1]]
>>> add(matrix1, matrix2)
[[3, -3], [-3, 3]]
```

My current code:

```python
list_3 = []


# Add function

def add(*args):
    for arg in args:
        for i in range(0, len(args)):
                list_3.append(arg[i - 1] + arg[i - 1] + arg[i - 1])
                print(f"Result: {list_3}")
```

My code does not work. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "My code doesn't work" is not a very useful problem description. You may want to edit the question and explain what your code is actually doing and why that is wrong. Include any errors that you're getting.

Comment: @Mark If you read the whole thing it said : Without using any third party libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple to do with a couple of nested comprehensions using `zip`:

```
>>> matrix1 = [[1, -2], [-3, 4]]
>>> matrix2 = [[2, -1], [0, -1]]
>>> [[a + b for a, b in zip(x, y)] for x, y in zip(matrix1, matrix2)]
[[3, -3], [-3, 3]]
```

or maybe using `map` and `sum` to build the inner lists:

```
>>> [list(map(sum, zip(x, y))) for x, y in zip(matrix1, matrix2)]
[[3, -3], [-3, 3]]
```

Comment: Nice one. I came up with `[list(map(operator.add, v1, v2)) for v1, v2 in zip(matrix1, matrix2)]`.

Comment: yes, I thought of using `map` for the inner lists at the same time you were commenting :D  although I generally prefer the readability of a list comprehension over `list(map(...`

Comment: Thanks it works! You just for got to make it a function other wise its great.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias for the second part

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the arguments, then iterate through the items of each arguments.

```
def add(*args):
    list_tmp = []
    for arg in args:
        for item in arg:
            list_tmp.append(item)
    return list_tmp
```

I also advise you to store the items in a local variable (`list_tmp`) and to return it: you can avoid a global variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to add each element now. It is written in the question.